# Different Python versions when launching from Terminal/C++ program

Tags: shell, terminal, qprocess

If I launch `python --version` from Terminal on `macOS`, I'm getting `3.9` version. The same is for `python3`.

But if I launch these from my C++ program (I use `QProcess`), I'm getting `2.7` for `python` and `3.7` for `python3`.

Why so?

Is there any way to launch the same python version as terminal launches?

Is there a way to find path to the latest python installed on the machine (I need to support macOS and Linux).

**Addition #1.** On another macOS machine, there is Python 3.10 installed in /Applications folder.
python3 --version shows expected 3.10 version, but my C++ program does not even see this python3, so macOS displays its system error message which suggests the user to install additional components (which does not work through).
[image]

Comment: why don't you use Python virtual environment?

Comment: @Devstorm21 What is it and how to use it from my C++ program?

Comment: It might be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685798/is-there-an-equivalent-of-pythons-virtualenv-for-c-c-programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with macOS. An app launched from the Dock has a different `PATH` environment variable than the shell has.
Here is a question about how to fix this: [Get bash $PATH from C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808960/get-bash-path-from-c-program)